# Android ScrollView isFinished?

Tags: android, scrollview

Just looking for an easy answer that I can't find on Google. Simply put. Is there a way to tell when ScrollView has stopped scrolling after a fling?

Comment: Perhaps http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29 ?

Comment: Thanks. That only gets triggered by scroll commands usually. So it gets called when the scroll is beginning not ending. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, after fling it comes in ideal state which means that your fling is over. For this you have to put listener on your list view Like `list.setOnScrollListener(this)`. Then you have to check in the listener that if it's in ideal state or not. like this

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) 
{          
     if(OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        your code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work for ScrollViews as well, or just ListViews? edit: looks like the setOnScrollListener is for List Views only. I need something like that for ScrollViews. Thanks though.